# How to connect the refrigerant lines of the DIY Mr Cool Mini Split in Tight Space?

Tags: hvac, mini-split

I want to mount the indoor unit of the DIY Mr Cool mini split on a wall inside the house that is a few inches across from a shed. Unfortunately, the proximity of the shed prevents me from accessing the refrigerant lines of the mini split and connecting it to the compressor's lines.

Since moving the shed is not an option either, would the only recourse be cutting a hole in the shed to pass through the refrigerant lines and have more space to connect the outdoor unit's lines? If so what tools would you recommend to cut through the shed's drywall (blue) and the wood siding from inside the shed?

[image: View of shed from inside of house]
View of shed from inside of house
[image: Distance between exterior wall and shed]
Distance between exterior wall and shed is 3 inches
[image: Refrigerant line is about 33 inches]
Refrigerant line is about 33 inches
[image: Interior of shed, with a roughly 3x33" rectangle marking cutout zone]
Interior of shed, with a roughly 3x33" rectangle marking cutout zone

Comment: With the MrCool you need to follow the installation instructions carefully, including choice of installation location.  That location does not work and you should not have chosen it.   If you can open up a hatch in the side of the shed to gain the access you need, OK, but it may be wiser to choose a different installation location.  Unfortunately on the MrCol units, you must work with their line-sets their way. Units like the Pioneer have more freedom to build and route your own line-set, but also oblige you to vacuum and nitrogen-test the lines.

Comment: Need a little clarity. Do you intend to run the lines into the wall cavity of the shed, or all the way through the shed wall to the interior.

Comment: the wall cavity

Comment: The *art of the possible* would tend to suggest that the location you want is not practical, and you should pick a more suitable location, or discover the possibility of moving the shed. Which will cost a lot less than moving the house, though that can also be done.